# DELETE query with WHERE operations

Tags: sqlite

how I can delete my rows from this way?

My table:

```
sqlite> .schema mytable
CREATE TABLE mytable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, hash TEXT, date TEXT);
```

I want delete all rows which (current time - stored time) > 10 seconds.
My query does not works:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE (datetime('now') - datetime(date)) > 10;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would work:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE datetime('now') > datetime(date, '+10 seconds')
```

Comment: This work, HalR! You just forgot to surround the second argument of datetime with single quotes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have to make sure that you have valid SQLite date and time strings in your `date` field (you don't show any examples of what data that field holds).

Then, you have to use one of the methods described here http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions to convert the dates into something subtractable.  Probably the most straightforward is to format each value with the `%s` formatting string:

```
 strftime('%s', 'now') - strftime('%s', date_col)
```